# carrierwave-crop showing large images out of visible area?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form, crop, jcrop

I'm using Rails 4 with simple_form, carrierwave, carrierwave-crop and jcrop to crop uploaded images.

```
= simple_form_for(@profile, html: {role: 'form'}) do |f|
  = f.cropbox :photo, width: 600, height: 600
  =' f.button :submit, "Crop", class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Everything works except one thing: When I upload an image that exceeds 600x600 in size, I can't see the whole image, hence can only crop part of it. E.g. 1200x1200 image: can only see top left quarter of the image.

Anyone got an idea?

**--- Update 1 ---**

I added this css snippet:

```
#card_photo_cropbox_wrapper {
  #card_photo_cropbox {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Which makes it look right, however it is not being cropped anymore.

Comment: No one had this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem using this gem https://github.com/kirtithorat/carrierwave-crop so I decided to throw it away and try different solution
finding easy way how to crop an image with carrierwave is really not fun

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Nope, still looking for some nice croping solution which really works

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem with cropping images with carrierwave, check it here. It uses cropit javascript library, load file to browser, user crop it and after onclick it is via ajax post to rails controller to process with carrierwave

[rails carrierwave - image url saved in db but file not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754469/rails-carrierwave-image-url-saved-in-db-but-file-not-saved/35772764#35772764)